# How to check received calls to indexer with NSubstitute

Tags: unit-testing, nsubstitute

Given this interface:

```
public interface ITest
{
  bool this[string parameter] { get; }
}
```

How to check received calls to the indexer?

```
ITest test = Substitute.For<ITest>();
test.Received()["value"];  // Won't compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error is:

> Error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement (CS0201)

To fix this, you can do a dummy assignment:

```
ITest test = Substitute.For<ITest>();
var ignored = test.Received()["value"];
```